# getopt fails to detect missing argument for option

Tags: c++, c, getopt

I have a program which takes various command line arguments. For the sake of simplification, we will say it takes 3 flags, `-a`, `-b`, and `-c`, and use the following code to parse my arguments:

```
    int c;
    while((c =  getopt(argc, argv, ":a:b:c")) != EOF)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
             case 'a':
                 cout << optarg << endl;
                 break;
             case 'b':
                 cout << optarg << endl;
                 break;
             case ':':
                 cerr << "Missing option." << endl;
                 exit(1);
                 break;
        }
    }
```

note: a, and b take parameters after the flag.

But I run into an issue if I invoke my program say with

```
./myprog -a -b parameterForB
```

where I forgot parameterForA, the parameterForA (represented by optarg) is returned as `-b` and parameterForB is considered an option with no parameter and optind is set to the index of parameterForB in argv.

The desired behavior in this situation would be that `':'` is returned after no argument is found for `-a`, and `Missing option.` is printed to standard error. However, that only occurs in the event that `-a` is the last parameter passed into the program.

I guess the question is: is there a way to make `getopt()` assume that no options will begin with `-`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the [POSIX standard definition](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html) for `getopt`. It says that

> If it [getopt] detects a missing
>   option-argument, it shall return the
>   colon character ( ':' ) if the first
>   character of optstring was a colon, or
>   a question-mark character ( '?' )
>   otherwise.

As for that detection,

> 1. If the option was the last character in the string pointed to by
>      an element of argv, then optarg shall
>      contain the next element of argv, and
>      optind shall be incremented by 2. If
>      the resulting value of optind is
>      greater than argc, this indicates a
>      missing option-argument, and getopt()
>      shall return an error indication.
> 2. Otherwise, optarg shall point to the string following the option
>      character in that element of argv, and
>      optind shall be incremented by 1.

It looks like `getopt` is defined not to do what you want, so you have to implement the check yourself. Fortunately, you can do that by inspecting `*optarg` and changing `optind` yourself.

```
int c, prev_ind;
while(prev_ind = optind, (c =  getopt(argc, argv, ":a:b:c")) != EOF)
{
    if ( optind == prev_ind + 2 && *optarg == '-' ) {
        c = ':';
        -- optind;
    }
    switch ( …
```

Comment: This has the added bonus of actually allowing arguments that start with `-` — they just can't be preceded by whitespace. (eg `my_prog -x-a`)

Answer (score 7):

If you are working in C++, boost::program_option is my recommendation to parse command line argument:

- [Boost::program_options library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Comment: I am not. I need to use getopt

Answer (score 4):

Full disclosure: I'm no expert on this matter.

Would [this example](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) from gnu.org be of use? It seems to handle the '?' character in cases where an expected argument was not supplied:

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
    {
       case 'a':
         aflag = 1;
         break;
       case 'b':
         bflag = 1;
         break;
       case 'c':
         cvalue = optarg;
         break;
       case '?':
         if (optopt == 'c')
           fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
         else if (isprint (optopt))
           fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
         else
           fprintf (stderr,
                    "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                    optopt);
         return 1;
       default:
         abort ();
    }
```

***update:*** Perhaps the following would work as a fix?

```
while((c =  getopt(argc, argv, ":a:b:c")) != EOF)
{
    if (optarg[0] == '-')
    {
        c = ':';
    }
    switch (c)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The ':' at the beginning of my string in the call to getopt() tells it to return a ':' in the event that a known parameter requires an argument. Also, I stated that "that <the desired behavior> occurs in the event that -a is the last parameter passed into the program." Which is exactly the case in your example.

Comment: Yes, you did specify that in your question. My fault for not paying close enough attention. Anyway, I posted an amendment with a short `if` statement that may provide the behaviour you are looking for. Best of luck!

Comment: @segfault: note that this code produces undefined results for options that don't take arguments. The implementation can advance `optarg` to the next `argv` entry because `optarg` is undefined if not used.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That sounds ominous. Are you saying the call to `optarg[0]` is undefined? `optarg` *must* be declared somewhere, otherwise the code wouldn't compile. Should the if statement simply check for `(optarg != NULL)` before reading `optarg[0]`?

Comment: @James: see the link in my answer for all the guarantees on `optarg`. I wouldn't count on `optarg[0]` working if `optarg` has no defined value. See my code for what I think would be the best workaround.

Comment: That looks much safer. Nice work.
@segfault: I would change the accepted answer to Potatoswatter's.

Comment: Yes, that ended up being the case. I added the check for if != null last night

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative for Boost-free projects, I have a simple header-only C++ wrapper for `getopt` (under The BSD 3-Clause License): https://github.com/songgao/flags.hh

Taken from `example.cc` in the repo:

```
#include "Flags.hh"

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  uint64_t var1;
  uint32_t var2;
  int32_t var3;
  std::string str;
  bool b, help;

  Flags flags;

  flags.Var(var1, 'a', "var1", uint64_t(64), "This is var1!");
  flags.Var(var2, 'b', "var2", uint32_t(32), "var2 haahahahaha...");
  flags.Var(var3, 'c', "var3", int32_t(42), "var3 is signed!", "Group 1");
  flags.Var(str, 's', "str", std::string("Hello!"), "This is a string, and the description is too long to fit in one line and has to be wrapped blah blah blah blah...", "Group 1");
  flags.Bool(b, 'd', "bool", "this is a bool variable", "Group 2");

  flags.Bool(help, 'h', "help", "show this help and exit", "Group 3");

  if (!flags.Parse(argc, argv)) {
    flags.PrintHelp(argv[0]);
    return 1;
  } else if (help) {
    flags.PrintHelp(argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  std::cout << "var1: " << var1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "var2: " << var2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "var3: " << var3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "str:  " << str << std::endl;
  std::cout << "b:    " << (b ? "set" : "unset") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few different versions of `getopt` around, so even if you can get it to work for one version, there will probably be at least five others for which your workaround will break. Unless you have an overwhelming reason to use getopt, I'd consider something else, such as [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/program_options.html).