# Reading multiple commands from one line of input in c++

Tags: c++

Say input can be 'x','y' and 'z' and for each commandX(),commandY() and commandZ() can be executed, respectively. Instead of having to type then pressing enter each time (ie: x (enter)  commandX() executed then y (enter) commandY() executed ...) how can I let the user input it into just one line (ie: x y z (enter)) and then the commands are made consecutively in the order of their input? ( ie: in x , y , z the order of execution will be commandX() then commandY() then commandZ())

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Extract an entire line from your input stream, and then process each command from that. You will probably want to wrap the output line in an [std::istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably looking for [getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219562/using-getopt-to-parse-program-arguments-in-c).

Yet, you can achieve the same result -- being shy some features --, with a while loop:

```
unsigned int i(1);
bool run_x(false), run_y(false), run_z(false);

while (i < argc and argv[i] == '-') {

    switch (argv[i + 1]) {

        case 'x':
            run_x = true;
            i += 2;
            break;

        case 'y':
            run_y = true;
            y_value = argv[i + 1];
            i += 3;
            break;

        case 'z':
            run_z = true;
            i += 2;
            break;

     }

}
```

And the execution of the program could be performed like:

```
./program -x -y 10 -z
./program -x -z
./program -z
./program -y 10 -z
...
```

Use the booleans and other variables to control what is/is not optional.

Comment: @KayTee What do you mean by *do that without* `./program`? How do you want to run your application?

Comment: I meant how do you it within the program not in command prompt.

Comment: @KayTee Well, it depends on what is your input. You must define what is to be passed as argument to your program, so that you can do whatever you want within it. If the case is that you have those `x`, `y`, and `z` coming from an input file, you simply need to replace the array `argv` with the array of characters read from your file.