# Reading multiple commands in one input in c++

Tags: c++, iostream

Here's what I have please tell me if I have to post everything.  What I want is if they type " tcc fcc (enter)" I want cube.rotateTopNeg90() then cube.rotateFrontNeg90() to work on the cube thats printed. 
edit: Sorry, that's my question above, right now the commands only work one at a time (ie: 'tcc' (enter) 'fcc' (enter) ...) I want to it to be something like this ( 'tcc' 'fcc' 'tcc' 'tcc'....(repeat as many times as they like) (enter)) then each are processed consecutively. That's why I can't just use cin. I've asked this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050388/reading-multiple-commands-from-one-line-of-input-in-c) but I really don't know how to do it exactly.

```
class RubiksCube
{
    public:

        RubiksCube::RubiksCube() { /*stuff here*/  }

        void display() { /*prints the cube unfolded here*/  }

        void rotateTopNeg90() { /*moves top of the cube counterclockwise*/ }

        void RubiksCube::rotateFrontNeg90() { /*moves front counterclockwise*/ }
}

//main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    RubiksCube cube;
    string s;  
    srand(time(0));
    while (1)
    { 
        string rotateTopNeg90 = "tcc";
        string rotateFrontNeg90 = "fcc";
        cube.display();
        cout << "COMMAND:";
        getline(cin,s);
        istringstream stream(s);

        if (s == rotateTopNeg90 )
            cube.rotateTopNeg90();

        if ( s == rotateFrontNeg90 )
            cube.rotateFrontNeg90();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think using `cin << s;` instead of `getline(...)` would do everything you want

Comment: And the 1 million euro (lets go cheap) question is?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would solve your problem; `std::getline` is taking in a whole line from  `std::cin` which is more than you want as your operations work on a per token basis. `std::cin` tokenises on whitespace so op>> is better suited to your application.

```
const std::string rotateTopNeg90   ="tcc",
                  rotateFrontNeg90 ="fcc";

while(std::cin >> s) {
   if (s == rotateTopNeg90 )
        cube.rotateTopNeg90();
   else if ( s == rotateFrontNeg90 )
       cube.rotateFrontNeg90();
   cube.display();
}
```