# c++: How to run a program taking string and filenames as arguments?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

I've to run a program sample `sample-code.cpp`. It is taking a string like `-create`, 2 file names: one as input `input.txt` and one as output filename `output.idx`as parameters and one integer `10`.

I should be able to run it from command line (mac Terminal/UNIX) using:

```
$sample-code -create input.txt output.txt 10
```

This is a snippet of `main()` code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // Creating New File
    if (strcmp(argv[1],"-create") == 0)
    {
        KeyFieldMax = atoi(argv[2]);
        InputFileName = argv[3];
        IndexFileName = argv[4];
```

when I type this command `$sample-code -create input.txt output.txt 10` I get this error :

`-bash: sample-code: command not found`.

Comment: What exactly is the question or problem? What you have should work, though it looks like it's expecting the integer before the filenames.

Comment: `KeyFieldMax = atoi(argv[2]);` did you miss that in the command lin arguments?

Comment: What about [using `getopt`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219562/using-getopt-to-parse-program-arguments-in-c) or something like it? Argument parsing is surprisingly tricky.

Comment: when I type this command `$sample-code -create input.txt output.txt 10` I get this error : `-bash: sample-code: command not found`. Maybe the program is not compiled.

Comment: @Dungeoun Suspected you are in the directory the `sample-code` was build to, just type `./sample-code`.

Comment: it says `Segmentation fault: 11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash: sample-code: command not found` is telling you that sample-code is not in bash's command path. if you're in the directory you build the program in, type `./sample-code` to run it.

Your error `Segmentation fault: 11` is an out of bounds array. You need to run a sanity check on the arguments to verify they are actually there before calling their position in the array:

```
if (argc < 4)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Urk! Not enough arguments!");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    KeyFieldMax = atoi(argv[2]);
    InputFileName = argv[3];
    IndexFileName = argv[4];
    ...
```

Comment: I checked it. My order of inputs was wrong and I was missing some arguments.